# Authenticate using IAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a meeting details of a Microsoft Office account. I tried to use the below code

```
IAuthenticationProvider authProvider = (IAuthenticationProvider) new UsernamePasswordProvider(
    "7d06733e-766f-4c63-846c-5b3825b2d638",
    Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/Calender.Read"),
    "professorx@proximex.com",
    "*******",
    NationalCloud.Global,
    "0df3f88a-c04e-40ac-8d41-84dbfb9e24d6",
    "*****");
```

I don't know why I'm getting below error:

> The type `com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.IAuthenticationProvider` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

my pom dependencies look like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph-auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

My code:

```
public class MicrosoftGraphHelper
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IAuthenticationProvider authProvider = (IAuthenticationProvider) new UsernamePasswordProvider(
            "7d06733e-766f-4c63-846c-5b3825b2d638",
            Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/Calender.Read"),
            "professorx@proximex.com",
            "*******",
            NationalCloud.Global,
            "0df3f88a-c04e-40ac-8d41-84dbfb9e24d6",
            "*******");

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = (GraphServiceClient) GraphServiceClient.builder()
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .buildClient();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install via Gradle works fine. Currently(7/19/2019) install via Maven doesn't work.

This is due to **com.microsoft.graph.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT** has not been updated. You can download the [source code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth) of msgraph-sdk-java-auth and exported it as jar file. Use this jar file instead of using com.microsoft.graph.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT. This will work, I have validated this.

Comment: i did add the profile. what the issue i see is there is no interface IAuthenticationProvider at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore. i found the issue in https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth/issues/12.
but the issue is not addressed. it would be good if a workaround is provided

Comment: @MohamedRafiudeen Try with `import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.IAuthenticationProvider;`

Comment: @MohamedRafiudeen See the import part in the answer.

Comment: I did use the same import. I think the issue is with usernamepasswordProvider class as mentioned in that git hub link in my above comment

Comment: @MohamedRafiudeen I see.  This is due to com.microsoft.graph.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT has not been updated. You can download the source code of msgraph-sdk-java-auth and exported it as jar. Use this jar file instead of using the com.microsoft.graph.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT. This will work, I have validated this.

Comment: @MohamedRafiudeen You can download the source code here. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth

Comment: thanks, it worked after exporting from jar and adding another dependency .
```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @MohamedRafiudeen I just found another way. Create a gradle project with `microsoft-graph-auth:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT` will be fine. There is something wrong with the code in maven repository(7/19/2019).

Comment: We've published the 0.2.0-SNAPSHOT which contains IAuthenticationProvider.